# Using SciPy T.ppf to get p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, scipy

Trying to test code creating P-value manually against SciPy. The [Scipy Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#t-test-and-ks-test) isn't the best, which makes it tought to know for sure what to do.

I am getting the correct t-stat and P-value with SciPy, but I'm not able to replicate the correct p-value manually - A friend steered me to `scipy.stats.t.ppf` - but I'm not getting a p-value from it.

What is the correct way to do `scipy.stats.t.ppf()`?

my version:

```
def t_test(sample, mu):
    mean = np.mean(sample)
    var = np.var(sample)
    sem = (var / len(sample)) ** .5
    t = abs(mu - mean)/sem
    df = len(sample) - 1
    p = scs.t.ppf(.95, df)
    return (t, p)
```

returns `(0.081500599630942958, 1.7291328115213671)`

scipy version:
`scs.ttest_1samp(sample, 4.123)`
returns `(statistic=0.079436958358141435, pvalue=0.93751577779749051)`

for testing, I'm using the following sample set and sample mu.

```
sample = [4.15848606,  3.86146363,  4.31545726,  3.3748772,
          4.67023082,  4.45950272,  3.85894915,  4.41089417,
          3.82360986,  3.79889443,  4.75884172,  3.27100914,
          4.08939402,  4.08904694,  5.62589842,  3.71445656,
          3.58463792,  4.42426443,  3.9671448 ,  4.39339124]

mu = 4.123
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce these results.  For instance, the mean of the sample is  4.132523, which hardly differs from `mu` at all, so I cannot obtain anything like these statistics.  What exactly is the distinction between `mu` and `mean` in your code?

Comment: @whuber `mu` is a made up estimation of the population mean - while `mean` is the mean of the sample found here in `sample`

I just copied and pasted the code into my terminal and it ran correctly - I edited the above to run my version within a function so you could run that easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the same results, change two things:

1. Change the estimation of the variance such that the divisor is N-1
2. Calculate the p-value using the cdf, that is the probability of getting a more extreme value, here using that the t-distribution is symmetric around zero. Note that the function you're comparing with does a two-sided test, and therefore, so do I.

I've marked the relevant lines with ###. The result is now the same as from the ttest_1samp function.

```
def t_test(sample, mu):
mean = np.mean(sample)
var = np.var(sample, ddof = 1) ###
sem = (var / len(sample)) ** .5
t = abs(mu - mean)/sem
df = len(sample) - 1
p = 2*(1-scs.t.cdf(t, df)) ###
return (t, p)
```

Comment: worked like a charm.  
Just adding the definition of `ddof` for any future visitors.   
“Delta Degrees of Freedom”: the divisor used in the calculation is N - `ddof`, where N represents the number of elements. By default `ddof` is zero."

Comment: I think the p value should be `2*min(1-scs.t.cdf(t, df), scs.t.cdf(t, df))` - depending on which side of the t-distribution you are.

Comment: @reox: That would be correct if 't' were the signed t-statistic, but note that in swmo's code, it is the absolute value. This ensures that we are always on the right side of the distribution.

Comment: @RubenvanBergen ah yes you are right, I missed the abs.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous posts, `p-value` can be computed with either of the following two lines of code, for a 2-sided t-test, indicating whether the extreme value (of the test statistic) is falling in the left or the right critical region (with -ve and +ve t-statistic values, respectively), as shown in the next figure.

```
2*(t.cdf(-abs(t_stat), dof))
2*(1 - t.cdf(abs(t_stat), dof))
```

where `t-stat` is the value of the `t-statistic` and `dof` is the associated degrees of freedom.

```
from scipy.stats import t
t_stat = 2.25
dof = 15
# p-value for 2-sided test
2*(1 - t.cdf(abs(t_stat), dof))
# 0.03988800677091664
2*(t.cdf(-abs(t_stat), dof))
# 0.03988800677091648
```

The below figure shows how the critical region for 5% level of significance looks like for a 2-sided t-test. For the above example, we can see that the null hypothesis can be rejected.

[image]

Comment: Although implementation is often mixed with substantive 
content in questions, we are supposed to be a site for 
providing information about statistics, machine
learning, etc., not code. It can be good to provide code 
as well, but please elaborate your substantive answer in 
text for people who don't read this language
well enough to recognize & extract the answer from the 
code.

Comment: @Sycorax provided some information about hypothesis test

Comment: That's all well and good, but it's not clear how this answers the question, which includes "how to compute the $t$ statistic" as one of its components.

Comment: @Sycorax I guess that part is already answered, just wanted to focus on different ways of computing the `p-value` that work correctly irrespective of the sign of the t-statistic (which is a part of the question too)